# Is there a way to change the size of elements on the screen in Ubuntu?

Tags: 15.04, screen

This is easily accomplished in Windows 8 and 10. I'm wondering if there's a way to do it in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods, which actually gives better control than Windows 8.1 (and probably 10).

**Settings >> Screen Display >> Scale for menu and title bars**

and

**Settings >> Appearance >> Launcher icon size**

---

What are you trying to acheive?